# How to make MapReduce work with HDFS

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, mapreduce

This might sound like some stupid question.
I might write a MR code that can take input and output as HDFS locations and then I really don't need to worry about the parallel computing power of hadoop/MR. (Please correct me if I am wrong here).

However if my input is not an HDFS location say I am taking a MongoDB data as input - mongodb://localhost:27017/mongo_hadoop.messages and running my mappers and reducers and storing the data back to mongodb, how will HDFS come into picture. I mean how can I be sure that the 1 GB or any sized big file is first being distributed on HDFS and then parallel computing is being done on it?
Is it that this direct URI will not distribute the data and I need to take the BSON file instead, load it up on HDFS and then give the HDFS path as Input to MR or the framework is smart enough to do this by itself?

I am sorry if the above question is too stupid or not making any sense at all. I am really new to big data but very much excited to dive into this domain.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are describing [`DBInputFormat`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/db/DBInputFormat.html). This is an input format that reads the split from an external database. HDFS only gets involved in setting up the job, but not in actual input. There is also an [`DBOutputFormat`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/db/DBOutputFormat.html). With an input like `DBInputFormat` the splits are logical, eg. key ranges.

Read [Database Access with Apache Hadoop](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/03/database-access-with-hadoop/) for a detailed explanation.

Comment: Well thanks for the wonderful link you have shared. Also i am rephrasing my question as "Will hdfs replication and distribution on data nodes will come into picture only when the MR job is on an hdfs file input or will hdfs will come into picture when the input is from local file system or URL"

Comment: HDFS distribution plays no role to the map phase if the input is not HDFS related. If the cluster is backed by HDFS then HDFS will play minor role in starting the job (the jar and config are copied into HDFS, from where there are 'localized' to the node running the task). HDFS *may* play a role in reduce output or in intermediate phases (eg. multi-stage MR jobs).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,I am not sure about MongoDb.

If you just wanted to know,how splitting is happening if we are using the data source is a table,then this is my answer when MapRed working with HBase.

we will use TableInputFormat to use an Hbase table in MapRed job.

From the http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#hbase.mapreduce.classpath

7.7. Map-Task Splitting
7.7.1. The Default HBase MapReduce Splitter

When TableInputFormat is used to source an HBase table in a MapReduce job, its splitter will make a map task for each region of the table. Thus, if there are 100 regions in the table, there will be 100 map-tasks for the job - regardless of how many column families are selected in the Scan.

7.7.2. Custom Splitters

For those interested in implementing custom splitters, see the method getSplits in TableInputFormatBase. That is where the logic for map-task assignment resides.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question, not stupid.

**1.**

"mongodb://localhost:27017/mongo_hadoop.messages and running my mappers and reducers and storing the data back to mongodb, how will HDFS come into picture. "

Under this situation, u needn't consider hdfs. U needn't do anything related with hdf. Just like write a multiple-thread application with each thread write data to mongodb.

In fact,  hdfs is independent to map-reduce, and map-reduce is also independent to hdfs. So, u can use them separately or together as your wish.

**2.**
if u want to input/output db to map-reduce, u show consider DBInputFormat, but that's another question.

Now, hadoop DBInputFormat only support JDBC. I'm not sure whether some mongodb version of DBInputFormat. Maybe U can search it or implement it by yourself.